# Stop rsync from backing up if too many files are being changed

Tags: rsync

Does anyone know of a way that I can tell rsync to not perform a backup if it detects and X amount of data will be changed? For example, if I run a backup and it detects and 25% of the data in the destination directory will be changed can I have it automatically abort that run and then I can evaluate and make a decision whether allow it or not.  I back up my machine every night but what I'm worried about is if my machine gets hit with a ransomware bug or another issue that causes a ton of my data gets destroyed or lost I really don't want it to propagate to my backup. I used to tool call synconvery and it had this feature but I don't think the tool is supported very well and I get a lot of permission and read errors that I don't see with any other tools.  Goodsync also has this feature but even though it runs on the Mac it doesn't support special characters in a file name and replaces it with an underscore when the file is copied.  I just think that will cause problems when I try to restore those file and it's being referenced wit that special character but can't be found because it has a damn underscore.  I like using rsync and I will eventually retrofit my script to use msrsync but I can't trust it if I can't get this protection in place.